# "toggle object" composition using closures

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

So many of my site's objects have very similar behaviour. They all need to "toggle", as in open and close.

I am using a `toggle()` method, which calls either `open()` or `close()` methods depending on the bool `isOpen`, but it seems I can only pass in one callback (in this pattern).

1. How can I pass in a different callback per toggle method invocation?
2. Should I move the `toggle()` method out of `Openable`?
3. Should I even have a `toggle()` method at all?

---

My "openable" behaviour object:

```
// Openable Behaviour
var Openable = function Openable() {
  var isOpen = false;

  // Open
  function open(callback) {
    isOpen = true;
    callback && callback();
  }

  // Close
  function close(callback) {
    isOpen = false;
    callback && callback();
  }

  // Toggle
  function toggle(callback) {
    isOpen ? close(callback) : open(callback);
  }

  return {
    get isOpen() {
      return isOpen;
    },
    open: open,
    close: close,
    toggle: toggle
  };
};
```

My other object which has openable behaviour:

```
var Other = function Other(element) {
  var openable = Openable();

  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    openable.toggle(/* what goes here? */);
  });

  function openCallback() {
    console.log("open!");
  }

  function closeCallback() {
    console.log("closed!");
  }

  return {
    target: element
  };
};

var myToggleObject = Other(myElement);
```

---

**Note:** - I am using the [**"revealing module pattern"**](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/) (I think), because it allows me to create an object without ever needing to use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `toggleCallback` method that does this:

```
function toggleCallback() { 
  openable.isOpen() ? openCallback() : closeCallback();
};
```

And pass it to the toggle method in your click listener.

Comment: Would this be a method of `Openable` or `Other`?

Comment: In `Other`, so you can keep the "one callback per action".

Comment: Right... I see. I was trying to get `toggle()` to make use of `open()` and `close()`. This is nice, because it keeps the `Openable` object more generic. It does make the `Openable` `toggle` method redundant though.

Comment: True. Once you're using `isOpen()` outside of `Openable`, you might as well write: `openable.isOpen() ? openable.close(closeCallback) : openable.open(openCallback)`

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How can I pass in a different callback per toggle method invocation?

You can pass multiple callbacks to a function, so

```
  function toggle(callback) {
    isOpen ? close(callback) : open(callback);
  }
```

becomes:

```
  function toggle(openCallback, closeCallback) {
    isOpen ? close(closeCallback) : open(openCallback);
  }
```

> 2. Should I move the toggle() method out of Openable?

Depends on the organization of your code. I think as long as it's clear that the function would be in 'Openable' it's fine.

> 3. Should I even have a toggle() method at all?

Depends on your code. I could see it being useful for user interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. I kinda had hoped that I wouldn't need an anonymous function for the click handler, but it seems to be the most appropriate.